# If statement in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script, and I can't get the if statement to work correctly.

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES = 'abc'
if ["$FILES" == "$1"]
then
    echo "ok";
fi
```

Why doesn't this if statement work correctly?

Comment: Ensure you have spaces around the square brackets.  They're actually a shorthand for a specific command and not brackets in the way you are used to.

Comment: I recommend you learn about [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) instead, or [some other system](https://cmake.org/) of handling building for you.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I will definitively check those. I know this is just me trying to do something and learn a little bit of bash at the same time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces before and after the condition:

```
if [ "$FILES" == "$1" ]
   ^^               ^^
```

Since you are using bash, you can use bash built-in `[[` and `]]` instead of the test command `[`.

Also see: [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem there was no pace after and before the brackets.